# Is my understanding of this paper correct? Not sure whether the bivariate method they mentioned means regression?

Tags: regression, methodology

I'm not sure if I understand the method used by this paper. Did they use simple linear regression multiple times? Because I'm only seeing one predictor variable and then multiple dependent variables.

Papers I've read before are quite clear on what specific method they use (t-test, ANOVA, regression, etc.), but here I'm really stumped because they only mention "univariate and bivariate" analysis.

Hope someone could help me understand the method they used here?

> Materials and Methods: The investigators designed a retrospective
> cohort study and enrolled a sample of 883 subjects who presented for
> evaluation of oral and maxillofacial fractures (OMF) between March 1
> and June 30 in the years 2018 through 2020. The primary predictor
> variable was the evaluation of OMF during a period with social
> distancing policies (2020 –experimental group) or without social
> distancing policies in place (2018 or 2019 –control group). The
> primary outcome variables were the facial fracture diagnosis, the
> abbreviated injury scale (AIS), injury severity score (ISS), and the
> mechanism of injury. Appropriate univariate and bivariate statistics
> were computed, and the level of significance was set at P <.05 for all
> tests.
>
> Results: The number of subjects presenting with OMF was lower during
> the period of social distancing (n = 235 in 2020) than during the
> periods without (2018: n = 330; 2019: n = 318). During the period of
> social distancing, there were more individuals who presented secondary
> to assault, whereas fewer individuals presented secondary to falls (P
> = .05). On average, those who presented in 2020 had more severe oral and maxillofacial injuries (mean AIS = 3.2+/-1.2 in 2020 vs 3.0+/-1.1
> in 2019 and 3.01+/-1.1 in 2018. P=.03) and more overall injuries (mean
> ISS = 20.7+/-13.1 in 2020 vs 19.2+/-12.5 in 2019; 17.8+/-12.8 in 2018.
> P =.03).

Thank you!

[Method and Conclusion photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFurg.jpg)

Paper link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1diWtp8DSwOzeqj1n0ASAftej2NEluv0l/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Where do they ever perform regression? Please paste in whatever context is necessary to understand & answer your question.
We want this thread to remain valuable even if the link goes dead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not sure actually that's why I decided to post. Papers I've read before are quite clear on the method they use like t-test, or if they mention their regression model. But here, they don't specifically say. Just "univariate and bivariate". Not sure how to interpret that into the specific method they used. Thanks!

Comment: The quotation is useless.  It is probably intended that you consult details in the paper, its appendices, or supplemental materials.

Comment: Right? I have already read the paper like 5x but I really can't figure out the method they used. I'm not sure why they didn't state the method outright, or maybe they did and I just don't get it? But this seems like a simple study.